# Nagios Notification interval and first notification delay

Tags: monitoring, nagios, nrpe, system-monitoring

I have used in past these two parameters in Nagios ( first_notification_delay, notification_interval ) and until now worked perfect for me. Now that I have added new checks which use nrpe command. the above two parameters are not effected. and i keep on receiving email every ten minutes.

Do I have to change any thing on the host nsclinet.cfg file?

Service definition I am using is

```
    define service {
    use                           generic-win-logfile
    host_name                     RuleS_TI_E405,RuleS_TI_E464
    service_description           check_logfilesSmsDispatcher_Process
    check_command                 check_nrpe!check_logfilesSmsDispatcher_Process
    }
```

It inherets from the following service template:

```
define service{  
  name                          generic-win-logfile  
  active_checks_enabled         1  
  passive_checks_enabled        0  
  parallelize_check             1  
  obsess_over_service           1  
  check_freshness               0  
  notifications_enabled         1  
  event_handler_enabled         1  
  process_perf_data             0  
  retain_status_information     1  
  retain_nonstatus_information  1  
  is_volatile                   1  
  check_period                  24x7  
  max_check_attempts            3  
  normal_check_interval         10               ; check every 5 minutes  
  retry_check_interval          2  
  contact_groups                admins  
  notification_options          u,c           ; notify unknown, warn,   >recovery  
  first_notification_delay      36  
  notification_interval         180               ; ignored for volatile   >services  
  notification_period           24x7  
  register                      0  

}
```

Comment: You've defined a template above, not a service (`register 0`). Show a real service definition where you're having trouble (add it to the question, leave the template if it's actually used).

Answer (score 0):

Notification intervals are IGNORED, if 'is_volatile' equals '1'.  This answer assumes you are receiving emails about the checks being either in an 'UNKNOWN' or 'CRITICAL' state.